# Show last created node in views

Tags: views

I'm using Drupal 7.
I have created two content types (A & B); content type B is referenced from content type A.
I want to create a view, I need to filter the nodes of content type B by showing the last node only (by date), for every node from content type A.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: so you want to have a listing, where As will be standing beside last referenced Bs ? (something like a last comment ?)

Comment: yes, i want to display a table which every row contain the last node b for every referenced node from a. like this  

node 1(last date) for node a1
node 2(last date) for node a2
...

Comment: quite hard to acheive i think. i'd probably suggest adding a computed field on A, that would store the reference to the last B and would be set upon saving the last B.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a relationship in Views. Then filter by creation date descending, and limit results to 1. 'Relationship' is how Views does a SQL JOIN.

It's non-trivial to describe, so I'll just link to a tutorial: http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/07/using-views-relationships-arguments-attachments