# One node for every referenced node in views

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I have a view that uses the table display mode. I want to show up the last created node for every referenced node; for example, I have two users, and I want to show the last post for both users.

> user number 1    |   last post title
>      user number 2    |   last post title

Comment: ? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27258/show-last-created-node-in-views

Comment: Instead of writing that you're using Drupal 7 in your question, please use the "7" tag.  This will allow your post to be searched more easily.

Comment: @PatrickKenny [tag:7] should only be used if the question is specific for Drupal 7, and not if the same answer applies to Drupal 6 too, or to any Drupal version.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [View Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module and create a view named Content View in which you may have:

**Fields**

- Content: Title

**Sort criteria**

- Content: Post date: Sort ascending or Sort descending

**Filter criteria**

- Content: Type *(or anything else to filter only certain posts)*

**Pager**

- Use pager: Display a specified number of items | 1 items

**Contextual filters**

- Content: Author uid

Now create another page view or a block view (whatever you want) named User View

**Relationships**

- Content: Author

**Fields**

- User: title
- Global: View (in this field select the view: Content View)

User View passes arguments in every raw to the Content View and thus it filters content by user id.

Answer (score 0):

I must say I didn't test it right now 
but you could try to aggregate on userid and sort your View on node creation date on group by User id and show limited number of nodes only, for example 1 per user.

In your View configuration:
go to Pager section 
set up Use pager: Display a specified number of items
Items per page: 1
More link: No

go to Advanced:
Use agregation: Yes

go to Fields:
click on field Date aggregation settings
go to Configure group settings for field Date
Aggregation Type: Minimum
Group Column: Value

Comment: i did what you wrote but it's not worked :(